# insert text of dropdown in database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've created a register page .

This my table for register in database :

[image]

This my table for education :

[image]

i fill education tabel and fil dropdown by that value .

code for `dropdownlist` :

```
    public static class Education
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEducationList()
    {
        using (AllameHelliDB db = new AllameHelliDB())
        {
            var List = (from a in db.Tbl_Educations
                        orderby a.EduID
                        select new SelectListItem { Text = a.EduName, Value = a.EduID.ToString() });
            return List.ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

.

```
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MotherEducation)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Paye,Allame_Helli.Models.Education.GetEducationList(), 
new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I need add `EduName` from table Education add in `MotherEducation` in `tabel Regsiter` . When i insert data return null .

How resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drop own is bound to the the `Paye` field, so this is the field that will get the EduID, if you want to get the text EduName for the selected option then you can do it from the Action itself, by reading the Paye property and retrive the Education object with this ID then fill the MotherEducation.

Or you can add another drop down list for the MotherEducation field but you will have to make both the Text and Value = EduName